# how to give margin/padding to a particular word in a sentence using css

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, sass

```
<h1>We rise by <span class="span1">lifting</span> others up</h1>
```

I want to give a margin-bottom only to the word "lifting" how should I do that?

Comment: You would need to make the span `display: inline-block` first - because margin-top/-bottom do not work on inline elements. And then you would have to add `vertical-align: bottom`, because otherwise the margin-bottom will "lift" the whole line up.

Comment: you can give .span1 relative position and bottom: 10px to move it upward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.span1 {
 vertical-align:super;
}
```

```html
<h1>We rise by <span class="span1">lifting</span> others up</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, is there any way to increase it?

Comment: @AbhishekSrinivasan you could add: `display: inline-block; position: relative; bottom: 10px;` and move it that way as suggested by a comment on your original question

Answer (score 0):

You can use the style tag to do some CSS styling.

```
<style>
    .span1{
        margin: 30px;
        padding: 12px;
    }

</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.span1 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1>We rise by <span class="span1">lifting</span> others up</h1>
```

Comment: This does not work. The OP wants the word "lifting" to be elevated above the rest of the text.